# How can I pass text value of element in each parent item?

Tags: javascript, window.location

I have comment block and it's child block with reply. Both have information block with a link to user profile and text value with user's name. I create link to send a private message to user, but it works only if I mark it with it's number in array.

Here is html markup:

```
<div class="comments_list">
<div class="comment_item">
    <div class="comment_body">
        <div class="info">
            <a href="http://test.com/users/test/" class="username">Test</a>
        </div>
        <p>Some parent text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="reply_comments">
        <div class="comment_body">
        <div class="info">
            <a href="http://test.com/users/fred/" class="username">Fred</a>
        </div>
        <p>Some child text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="comment_item">
    <div class="comment_body">
        <div class="info">
            <a href="http://test.com/users/ken/" class="username">Ken</a>
        </div>
        <p>Another parent text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="reply_comments">
        <div class="comment_body">
        <div class="info">
            <a href="http://test.com/users/jack/" class="username">Jack</a>
        </div>
        <p>Another child text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Here is the code:

```
var infobars = document.querySelectorAll('.info');
var usernames = document.querySelectorAll('.info > .username');

function clickPm(event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    alert(window.location.pathname = '/conversation/' + usernames[1].innerHTML);
   //alert   here to show that username passed properly
}


var newContainer = document.createElement('span');
    newContainer.className = 'container';
var newBtn = document.createElement('a');
    newBtn.className = 'pmlink';
    newBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('send message'));
    newBtn.href="#";
    newBtn.onclick = clickPm;
    newContainer.appendChild(newBtn);
    infobars[1].appendChild(newBtn);
```

Sorry for my bad JavaScript knowledge and newbie question.

Hope you can help me to resolve it in pure JavaScript without jQuery or else.
[Demo on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/glebcha/QsYwp/2/)

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Trying to get name of user (text value from "a" tag) from "info" in "comment_body" and pass it to function on click which will open new link in current tab with users's name in address. I need it to be for each "comment_body" (each parent comment and child block with reply). Sorry for such a complicated explanation. Please, try demo on jsfiddle.

Comment: Posted an answer try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
**Updated**

```
function clickPm(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    var username = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('a.username').innerText;
    alert(window.location.pathname = '/conversations/' + username);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but no luck with real document (demo was very simplified copy). Updated jsfiddle with used markup and full code. Can you try it here http://jsfiddle.net/glebcha/8ajAV/ ?
Hope you can help me.

Comment: Vote up requires 15 points of reputation, but I have only 12 :(

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(infobars, function(el) {     
    var newContainer = document.createElement('span');
    newContainer.className = 'container';

    var newBtn = document.createElement('a');
    newBtn.className = 'pmlink';
    newBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('send message'));
    newBtn.href="#";
    newBtn.onclick = clickPm;
    newContainer.appendChild(newBtn);

    el.appendChild(newBtn);
});
```

Not exactly sure what you're asking here but I think this is what you want..

Comment: Oh, prototypes. Thanks, will try your suggestion.